# How to show the details into component in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my activity, there are Five fragments when user click on next second fragments is displayed.
  **problem statement:** User enter the details in first fragment (Registration form) and move to the next page and if the user clicks back then  I want the data to be preserved in Form(first fragment) How can I do that please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried viewpager ?

Comment: welcome to SO.Please Shere your java and XML file so we can help you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YUF7fz1vCouklHQhjEPQiqj1OWNEMPT2 here is link